# Bash script to read from a file and execute commands

Tags: java, bash, file

I want a bash script that reads the java arguments from a file and executes java with them

```
jvm_arguments=$(cat jvm-args)
exec java $jvm_arguments
```

The problem is that it does not work very well with this jvm-args file:

```
-Xms128m -Xmx512m -Dhostname=$(hostname)
```

The command hostname is not executed and replaced.

How can I get the hostname command executed? so that I get:

```
exec java -Xms128m -Xmx512m -Dhostname=MyMachine
```

Thanks.

Comment: Be careful with this.  There is a reason why bash does not do this sort of thing automatically: it can be a gaping security hole.

Comment: `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()` might be another solution (http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost%28%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use eval to evaluate your runtime variables. Like this (not tested):

```
jvm_arguments=$(cat jvm-args)
eval java $jvm_arguments
```

Comment: If bash only, `jvm_arguments=$(< jvm-args)` will cause the shell to read the file rather than needing another cat process.

Answer (score 1):

Store the whole command in file, for example, `run.sh`

```
exec java -Xms128m -Xmx512m -Dhostname=$(hostname) ...
```

If you want current `bash` process to be terminated, call with `. run.sh`